# vbscript failed will error 0x80041002 on Windows 10

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I’m running this vb script which is part of a larger one on multiple Windows 10 machines but for some reason it failed on a specific one.

```
Const HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT = &H80000000 
'On Error Resume Next 
strComputer = "." 
Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
```

and get this error

```
C:\temp\test.vbs(4, 1) (null): 0x80041002
```

The script worked OK on Win10 machine till few weeks ago and suddenly stopped, so I suspect some windows update or security policy is the cause for it but still unable to solve this.

Any ideas ?
I'm running it on a command prompt opened as Administrator. Also verified WMI service is running and winmgmt /verifyrepository returned this:
WMI repository is consistent

Comment: Maybe some change to your AV? Do you get the same error if you simplify it to `Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")`?

Comment: Note: HKCR is a combined view of `HKCU\Software\Classes` and `HKLM\Software\Classes`. Avoid accessing HKCR. Go directly to the HKCU or HKLM.

Comment: Use StdRegProv only when necessary (e.g. `EnumKey`). If you just need to read or write a specific value, use the WshShell `RegRead` or `RegWrite` methods.

Comment: Yes I also get the error when using Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")

Comment: Do you have to use StdRegProv? Can you use RegRead and RegWrite instead?

Comment: Hmm, I’m running this code from a setup .msi file and my concern is that user that install the .msi will have permissions issue if I will use a different way.
Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv") 
…
objReg.DeleteValue HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,strKeyPath,strEntryName

Comment: Presumably the MSI is running elevated already. Just try replacing that code with `Set oWSH = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")` followed by `oWSH.RegDelete "HKCR\SomeKey\SomeValue"`. Using your variables, that second line would be `oWSH.RegDelete "HKCR\" & strKeyPath & "\" & strEntryName`. Be sure to double-check the backslashes.